# Single-threaded embedded Jetty?

Tags: embedded-jetty

How can I make an embedded Jetty instance single-threaded?

I have tried

```
server.setThreadPool(new QueuedThreadPool(1))
```

but it complains that there are not enough threads in the pool, and hangs. This still happens even if I use a `SocketConnector` instead of a NIO connector.

(The reason I want this is I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743894/integration-tests-for-google-app-engine-java) - which I currently have a bounty on, by the way! - and Google's `LocalServiceTestHelper` only seems to take effect in the current thread.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SocketConnector` needs 2 threads - one to wait for connections, and one to service a connection. Other connectors may need even more, so use a `SocketConnector`.

Also, you **must** ensure that each connection is closed on the client end before you make another connection - otherwise the server will keep it open for a while, in case any more HTTP requests are to be sent. Make sure you disable Keep-Alive.

Comment: Different use case, same task: remote function/procedure/method call server that allows developers to ignore any thoughts about multi-threading complications when implementing the method to be executed by the server. To scale, start more (think docker).